# Is it usual to wrap a variable in an useless `id` call to avoid eta-conversion issues on proofs?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Using a language similar to Morte/CoC, I'm trying to prove the simple statement `there are lists of arbitrary lengths`. For that, I wrote the following type:

```
∀ n:Nat ->
(ThereIs (List Nat)
  (Equal Nat 
    (List.length Nat l) 
    n)))
```

`ThereIs` is the dependent pair (Sigma). All is church-encoded. To prove it, I wrote the following proof:

```
λ n:Nat ->
(ThereIs.this (List Nat)
  (λ l:(List Nat) -> (Equal Nat (List.length Nat l) n))
  (List.replicate Nat n Nat.Zero)
  (Equal.refl Nat n))
```

Weirdly, I get a type mismatch error between `d` (i.e., the free variable of type Nat) and `λ c:* -> λ b:(c -> c) -> λ a:c -> (d c b a)`. But that later term, when eta-reduced, is just `d`! Since I don't have an eta-reducer ready, I instead made this following "useless identify" function:

```
λ n: Nat ->

λ Nat:* ->
λ Succ: (Nat -> Nat) ->
λ Zero: Nat ->

(n Nat Succ Zero)
```

Now, by applying that useless id to every occurence of `n`, I "un-eta" it, causing the proof to check. I'd like to gain any kind of insight of what is going on here. Is this "useless id" function a known/used pattern on writing proofs? Why isn't the calculus of contructions able to type-check this proof without this little help? Is there any deep reasoning behind this phenomena or is it just how things are for no special reason?

Comment: You mean eta not alpha, right?

Comment: Yes sorry @ReidBarton

Comment: I think specially-typed `id`s of all varieties -- not just eta equalities -- are very common in proof systems. Half the tactics in Coq end up translating into `id` spelled in an especially exciting way.

Comment: Church-encoded Sigma? I want to see this. Where is `l` from `List.length Nat l` bound? Instead of eta-reduction you can incorporate eta-expansion in your type checker: an attempt to unify `f` with `\x -> e` results in eta-expanding `f`, so the unification problem becomes `(\x -> f x) =?= (\x -> e)` and you can proceed further structurally. Ideally this machinery should be type-directed, so e.g. whenever two expressions of type `Top` are unified, you don't need to unify them structurally and can just conclude that they are the same.

Comment: @user3237465 all the code is [here](https://github.com/maiavictor/sol), I learned how to encode arbitrary GADTs on CoC after a lot of help from Gabriel, András etc. - I was trying to avoid messing with the compiler further, I thought it was really good and elegant that way, which is why this issue quite bothered me ):

Answer (score 4):

You need to add eta to your conversion checking algorithm. That can be done in several ways, the simplest two are

- Type-directed as in page 22 of [Ulf Norell's thesis](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/thesis.pdf) and used in Agda
- Untyped as used in Coq AFAIK

Untyped eta conversion is complete for functions, and it's also simpler and faster than the typed version (no need to recompute or cache types in neutral applications) in our case. The algorithm goes like this:

We first check the case when both values are lambdas as usual. However, we check two additional cases after that, when only one side is lambda. In these cases, we apply the lambda body to a new generic variable (as usual), and also apply the other term to the same variable, and check equality of the  resulting values.

That's all of it! It's actually very simple, and doesn't have much performance cost. Note that we don't need to implement eta reduction, or strong eta normalization, since eta conversion check is easily done on weak-head normal values on the fly.

Comment: "Typed eta conversion is only really necessary for eta conversion of unit types" — of any irrelevant propositions which can consist of `Bot`, `_->_`, `Sigma`, propositional truncation and even user-defined `data` (as opposed to `record`), e.g. you could have a system where you can prove that `Vec A n` is a `Prop` if `A` is a `Prop` (which works, because the shape of the `Vec A n` container is `Top`, i.e. statically known, so there is scope for further generalization (any container with propositional shape and positions, I guess?)) and reify unification with this knowledge.

Comment: @user3237465 those are advanced features even in the context of modern dep. languages, therefore I thought them out of question scope.  `Prop < Type` subtyping, inference, or even instance resolution based `Prop` identification seems interesting to me as well. However, I currently think that it's worth to consider putting irrelevant things in boxes during elaboration, instead of having type-directed unification (for performance reasons).

Comment: @user3237465 Also, I think propositional truncation is in a different league. Unification traditionally solves equations only up to definitional equality, which is proof irrelevant, but if we consider higher constructors as solutions, we need proof relevant unification. In Agda, proper `--without-K` for unification in patterns was quite a [complexity jump](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~jesper.cockx/unifiers-as-equivalences/draft.pdf), and I imagine it would not be easier for unification on right-hand sides/implicits.

Comment: What's your strategy of unifying boxes? Two boxes are equal only if they are of the same type, right? In higher-order unification `(x y : || A ||), x =?= y` is solved by `()` — not by the higher constructor. In the same way type constructors in higher-order unification are injective unlike in "pattern matching" unification. This is discussed in the paragraph right before the "9. Conclusion and future work" section in the paper you linked.

Comment: Prop. truncation from HoTT and `Prop` boxes as in classic OTT are very different. In the latter case (which I referred to when I advocated boxes), contents are considered definitionally equal, and this kind of boxing is generally useful for implementation of eta for unit too, because there the contents are def. equal as well. With prop. truncation, `(| zero | =?= | suc zero |) : | Nat |` is only solvable with the higher constructor, and if  we solve it thus, subsequent code may need to be transported along truncation (which seems really complicated). I don't think I fully get you though.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I confused judgmental truncation (aka `Squash`) with propositional truncation. Sorry for the noise. My point about boxes is that `Top` and `A -> Top` are both units (in a sense), so they both can be erased, but `erase tt == erase (const tt)` doesn't hold. So you have to keep some type information and perform type-directed unification anyway. Or did I just misunderstand you?

Comment: In the checking/unification algorithms I know we only ever conversion check terms with equal types (or maybe types that are equal modulo unsolved constraints - this is OK to do is some sytems). So, if `erase a =?= erase b` comes up, we know that `a` and `b` have the same `Prop` type.